# Pandas: How to iterate over level one and randomly select from level 2 then add subselection to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am just starting with pandas and may have bitten off more than I can chew. I have a Dataframe with a MultiIndex over which I want to loop over the 1st (`'type'`) level, then randomly select from the values from the 2nd (`'lwc'`) level, and then create a sub Dataframe of this subselection which I then add to another Dataframe.

Dataframe is `spec_df` with level names:

```
spec_df.columns.names
FrozenList([u'type', u'lwc', u'rad', u'cl_top', u'wvc', u'aot', u'press', u'sza', u'phi0', u'umu', u'phi'])
```

The code I have so far:

```
rand_clds = pd.DataFrame([])

for l1 in spec_df.columns.levels[0]:
    l2l = spec_df[l1].columns.levels[0]
    rand_l2 = np.random.choice(l2l)
    rand_clds[l1, rand_l2] = spec_df.ix[[l1, rand_l2]]
```

Works well up to the start of the loop. `l2l` contains all the values of level `'lwc'` and not just the subset of `l1` in `'type'`.

Comment: If I change this to not select a random column from the list, but only the first column would anyone be able to help. a bit stuck. ie. I loop over level 1 values and select only the 1st occurrence of the level 2 column?

Comment: Give representative example of ```spec_df```  and your expected output ```rand_clds```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `spec_df` looks like this:

```
In [141]: spec_df
Out[141]: 
      foo bar foo baz    bar
        A   B   B   C  A   D
        1   2   3   1  2   3
baz C   2   2   9   6  8   5
    D   7   8   0   6  7   8
qux C   3   8   6   9  2   3
    D   1   2   6   2  9   8
    C   5   8   4   8  9   1
```

Then you can subselect columns by passing a list of tuples to `spec_df`. For
example, if `cols` equals

```
In [140]: cols
Out[140]: [('baz', 'A', '2'), ('foo', 'B', '3'), ('bar', 'D', '3')]
```

then

```
In [147]: spec_df[cols]
Out[147]: 
      baz foo bar
        A   B   D
        2   3   3
baz C   8   9   5
    D   7   0   8
qux C   2   6   3
    D   9   6   8
    C   9   4   1
```

That would solve the problem of how to select a sub-DataFrame, if only we could
construct `cols`. That turns out to be not so hard using plain Python. Simply
collect the columns in a dict which maps the first column level value to the
full column tuple:

```
columns = spec_df.columns
seen = dict()
for col in columns:
    seen.setdefault(col[0], []).append(col)
# >>> seen
# {'bar': [('bar', 'B', '2'), ('bar', 'D', '3')],
#  'baz': [('baz', 'C', '1'), ('baz', 'A', '2')],
#  'foo': [('foo', 'A', '1'), ('foo', 'B', '3')]}
```

Then use `random.choice` to select one column tuple for each key in
`seen`:

```
cols = [random.choice(seen[firstcol]) for firstcol in seen]
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
random.seed(1)
spec_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(5,6)),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['foo','bar','foo','baz','baz','bar'],
                                       list('ABBCAD'),
                                   list('123123')]),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['baz']*2+['qux']*3,
                                     list('CDCDC')]))

columns = spec_df.columns
seen = dict()
for col in columns:
    seen.setdefault(col[0], []).append(col)
cols = [random.choice(seen[firstcol]) for firstcol in seen]
print(spec_df[cols])
```

yields

```
      baz foo bar
        A   B   D
        2   3   3
baz C   8   9   5
    D   7   0   8
qux C   2   6   3
    D   9   6   8
    C   9   4   1
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer my own question exactly. I leave that to the genius that will, it there is one. Here is something that simply selects the 1st column for every value of the 1st level I loop over. Not ideal but, yes it gives me something:

```
rand_clds = pd.DataFrame([])

for l1 in spec_df.columns.levels[0]:
    rand_clds[l1] = spec_df[l1].icol(0)
```

The problem is that it the `rand_clds` dataframe doesn't have the column names etc. of the original dataframe. I can at least plot something with this.